# NullPointerException on MAX value retrieval from Dao in Room database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room, dao, roomdb

From the `Room` database, I want to get the `MAX` value for a specific column returned as a `Long` value, but it throws the `NullPointerException` error below when I add the very first item into the shopping list. How can I fix this?

**Exception**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.lang.Number.longValue()' on a null object reference
```

**ShoppingListEntity**

```
@Entity(tableName = "shopping_lists")
data class ShoppingListEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Long = 0L,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    val name: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "number_of_items")
    val numberOfItems: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "list_total")
    val listTotal: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "sort_order")
    val sortOrder: String
)
```

**ShoppingListItemEntity**

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "shopping_list_items",
    foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(
        entity = ShoppingListEntity::class,
        parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
        childColumns = arrayOf("shopping_list_id"),
        onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
    )]
)
data class ShoppingListItemEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Long = 0L,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "shopping_list_id")
    var shoppingListId: Long = 0L,
    
    ...

    @ColumnInfo(name = "custom_sort_index")
    val customSortIndex: Long
)
```

**Dao**

```
@Query("SELECT MAX(custom_sort_index) FROM shopping_list_items WHERE shopping_list_id = :listId")
suspend fun getMaxCustomSortIndex(listId: Long): Long
```

**Repository**

```
override suspend fun getMaxCustomSortIndex(listId: Long): Long {
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        shoppingListItemDao.getMaxCustomSortIndex(listId)
    }
}
```

**Use Case**

```
class GetMaxCustomSortIndexInItemsTableUseCase@Inject constructor(
    private val shoppingListItemsRepository: ShoppingListItemsRepository
) {
    suspend operator fun invoke(listId: Long): Long {
        return shoppingListItemsRepository.getMaxCustomSortIndex(listId)
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
suspend fun addShoppingListItemToDb() {
    if (!_shoppingListScreenState.value.isNameError && !_shoppingListScreenState.value.isCategoryError) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val listId = _shoppingListState.value!!.id

            //Throws Null Pointer Exception here
            val maxCustomSortIndex = getMaxCustomSortIndexInItemsTableUseCase(listId)

            val item = _shoppingListItemState.value
            addShoppingListItemUseCase(item.copy(customSortIndex = maxCustomSortIndex + 1))
            _listItemsLoadingState.value = ListItemsState.Success(_shoppingListItemsState.value)

            setStateValue(IS_SCROLL_TO_LAST_ITEM_IN_LAZYCOLUMN_STR, true)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:-

```
@Query("SELECT coalesce(MAX(custom_sort_index),0) FROM shopping_list_items WHERE shopping_list_id = :listId")
```

Then in the case of null it will be replaced with 0, if the max value is not null, then as it appears first in the list of parameters passed to the ***coalesce*** function it will return that value.

- this assumes that 0 would be an acceptable/usable value in this scenario. (0, as the 2nd parameter, could be any suitable value).

See https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#coalesce

- Instead of ***coalesce*** you could use the ***[ifnull](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull)*** function, they basically do the same thing in this use (2 parameters).